# No me ejecuta query SQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una query para ordenar registros numericos de la bd que es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE test AS t2 
SET t2.id = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS t1 
             WHERE t1.id < t2.id) + 1;
```

Si la ejecuto desde phpmyadmin funciona correctamente y me reordena los registros sin problemas. Pero cuando la ejecuto desde php no da error pero no hace nada. el codigo que tengo en el archivo php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "bd");

/* verificar conexion */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Error enconexión: ". mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

$sql = "UPDATE test AS t2 SET t2.id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS t1 WHERE t1.id < t2.id) + 1";

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

sabe alguien que me puede estar fallando en el php para que no ejecute la query?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que de acuerdo con [la doc. de MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) no tienes la sintaxis correcta, es decir:

- Como primer argumento de la función abajo mencionada debes pasar a la variable que tiene la conexión
- La consulta la debes pasar como segundo argyumento del método `mysqli_query`

---

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "bd");

/* verificar conexion */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Error enconexión: ". mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE test AS t2 SET t2.id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS t1 WHERE t1.id < t2.id) + 1");

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado perfectamente. Estoy aprendiendo como podrás imaginar jeje y hay veces que con tanta información se atasca uno y no ve las cosas. Mil gracias.